# termux and tkinter on android

Tags: tkinter, termux

I installed termux on my android device (Pixel C), and successfully installed python 3.6.2 too; after downloaded (with pip) some libraries like pillow (there were some problems, but with online forums I solved it), vk, etc...

Tkinter should be preinstalled on python, but it wasn't (like some other modules like time, random etc.). All this modules - tkinter, that should be preinstalled, are not there - and it is not possible to install them.

pip install tkinter -> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tkinter.

If I try with: apt-get install python3-tk Still nothing - error placing file. apt-get update and apt upgrade didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

Termux support only terminal, it does  not support GUI 
https://plus.google.com/+CoryPollard/posts/98suMC1Asq1

Answer (score 0):

You must first set up a graphical interface

https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Graphical_Environment

Then install the package:

pkg install python-tkinter

I hope this has served you well.